# What can cause fonts and images to be downloaded twice when using React with SSR?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I am using create-react-app and have configured SSR using an Express server.

When I disable JavaScript, everything works perfectly (assets are downloaded and displayed).

When I enable JavaScript, the website loads from server as expected but then hydrate triggers assets to be downloaded again (somehow, these assets are not cached by Firefox).

[image: React double request bug]

Here are the headers for `/static/media/fonts/open-sans-latin-400.woff2` (both requests appear to be identical except for `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` vs `Accept-Encoding: identity`).

[image: First request]

[image: Second request]

What can cause this behavior?

Comment: What are the exact urls the assets are loaded from? Take a single font that's downloaded twice and compare them. A hunch is they are bundled in two different bundles maybe? It's hard to tell from your screenshot

Comment: Hey @Dominik, thanks for helping... the URLs are identical. I am so puzzled.

Comment: Can you provide a details screenshot for a single font for both downloads?

Comment: @Dominik, yes, on it!

Comment: @Dominik, done!

Comment: Mhh no idea. Fonts are highly opimized in browsers and are only downloaded when they are actually used on the page not when they are just referenced in CSS. So there is likely some magic going on here. Sorry if I think of something I come back here

Comment: @Dominik, I am using font preloading btw... that being said, some images are also downloaded twice.

Comment: Maybe it's a change in a state of your app, which generates a re-rendering. Look closer, how often, and (if it happens) why the page rerenders.

Comment: Thanks @suther. I believe the second download is triggered by `hydrate`. The part I don't understand is why the files are not cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue...

I use [Express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) to serve static assets.

By [default](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static), [express.static](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) is set to not cache assets (`Cache-Control: public, max-age=0`).

The following solved the caching issue that caused fonts and images to be downloaded twice.

```
$ cat .env
EXPRESS_MAX_AGE=60000
```

```js
const expressStaticOptions = {
  maxAge: process.env.EXPRESS_MAX_AGE ?? 0,
}
app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, "build"), expressStaticOptions))
```

The reason I don't set `60000` by default is to handle caching config using [Nginx](https://nginx.org/en/) in production.